# Constructor for my dynamic array

Tags: c++, constructor, dynamic-arrays

Am I even utilizing my `INITIAL_CAPACITY`(a constant that i set to `10` in my header file).

Should I instead declare `current_capacity= INITIAL_CAPACITY` and then `data = new int[current_capacity]`?

```
IntVector::IntVector()
  {   
     data = new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
     current_capacity = 0;
     current_size = 0; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should I instead declare `current_capacity= INITIAL_CAPACITY` and then `data = new int[current_capacity]`?

Yes of course, intuitively that's the more clean definition.

Your code should look like:

```
IntVector::IntVector() 
    : current_capacity(INITIAL_CAPACITY)
    , data(new int[current_capacity])
    , current_size(0)
{}
```

`current_capacity` should always be synchronized to what you've currently allocated for `data`.

Comment: I would not suggest using `new int[current_capacity]` but rather `new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY]`.  If `data` is listed before `current_capacity` in the class then `current_capacity` will not be initialized when you get to `data(new int[current_capacity])`.  It is best not to have to rely on the order of variables in a class.

Comment: @NathanOliver There will be a warning issued about your point, and I've been proposing that to make the need for synchronization clearer.

Comment: No problem.  I just think using `new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY]` makes the code less fragile.